# SecureW2 equivalent on Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ieee802.1x

I'm studying at the HAN (Hogeschool Arnhem & Nijmegen) in the Netherlands, where we have a wireless network that is secured with SecureW2 (IEEE 802.1x).

The SecureW2 client is not available for Linux, so I'm trying to get the config right myself. On the web I found that NetworkManager should be able to handle this, but it doesn't work for me. Trying both knetworkmanager and the network widget (I'm using Kubuntu 9.04 + KDE 4.3) I entered the settings:

- Security: WPA-EAP
- TTLS
- My username and pass
- Phase 2: PAP

But it does not work. If connecting trough the widget, nothing happens when I click. When using knetworkmanager, it tries to connect but goes on forever.

How can I get this to work? Are there any logs I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by ditching knetworkmanager. Nm-applet (GNOME's network manager icon) does this well, out of the box, and works fine in KDE. It's also much better in other ways.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.I used the default network manager in Unity.
My settings are:

- Security : WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
- Authentication : Tunnelled TLS
- Anonymous Identity : (I left this blank,but I think they have configured the network that way so it won't ask for this kind of Identity)
- CA certificate : (I left this blank as well,but again this has to do with the configuration of the wireless network,so it might be different in other educational institutes)
- Inner Authentication : PAP
- Username : (the one given from your school)
- Password : (the one given from your school)

After I press save on he configuration window, I get a warning window pop-up telling me that I haven't used any CA Certificates.  I always press ignore.

I tested to my school's network and it works, without installing knetworkmanager.

The solution to my problem was given by jrg from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

From [Please make a linux version of securew2](http://www.securew2.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=309)

> Both the KNetworkManager (KDE) frontend of wpa_supplicant as well as the NetworkManager frontend (Gnome) support EAP-TTLS. Gnome does it a little bit better than KDE, but KDE can also be made to work ([see **this post**](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=396347) for more information). I'm using KNetworkManager with openSUSE 11.1 every day to connect to an WPA2-Enterprise network with EAP-TTLS authentication.

Also check the link in the quoted text.

Comment: I have the same problem as Comment #10 in the "see this post" link